# Analyze memory usage of a C program

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I know there are a lot of similar questions(i am not sure for a possible duplicate) but my question is specific enough.I am running a C program in Windows and Unix and i am experiencing a segmentation fault(core dumped) error.I know the source of that error.It's because i sometimes use a huge amount of memory by allocating a big array of integers.The size of my array is different every time but i can't(mostly i don't want to) use dynamic allocation of memory.

What i want is to find a way or a tool to analyze the memory usage of my C program in order to set a limit to the size of that array or in any other big memory allocation i make.To be more specific let's say that the size of that array is between 4*(2^4) bytes and 4*(2^50) bytes.The minimum is only 64 bytes but the maximum is an enormous value.How can i find out how much memory my program needs and what is a proper limit to set? 
I define an array like this:

`int bigarray[rows][columns]` ,

where rows is between 2^4 and 2^50 and columns is between 4 and 50.

Comment: So you're using VLAs, right? Then just check for `sizeof(array) > KNOWN_LIMIT_THAT_OVERFLOWS_THE_STACK`

Comment: 2^50 is into the petabytes.  Good luck!

Comment: @RichieHindle I will set the limit a lot less than 2^50,maybe 2^10

Comment: 2^50 is even more that MAX int (32 bit), can `[]` even handle that?

Comment: printf("%d\n", sizeof(bigarray)); as suggested above.  As to hwat may be proper/useful limits, depends on the platform (Windows, Linux, etc.).  Also you might be able to squeeze a lot more size from the program using a malloc/new approach.

Comment: I need a minimum limit according to as many platforms as possible

Comment: Side note: See answers to this question for using malloc/new instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885016/printf-command-causing-a-seg-fault/16885058#16885058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get memory from the heap (malloc() and friends) instead of using the stack.  The heap permits much larger allocations.

```
int *bigarray = malloc(sizeof(int)*rows*columns);

/* to access row r, column c */
bigarray[r*columns+c] = 42;
/* equivalent method to access row r, column c */
*(bigarray+r*columns+c) = 42;
```

Comment: allocating from the heap will make a bigger allocation possible?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use tool `valgrind` to check for memory consumption as well as memory leaks.

Below is link to `Massif: a heap profiler`,hope it helps you.

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Comment: If i will use a tool like valgrind i prefer to use a tool running on windows.Do you suggest any?

Comment: Sorry @Dchris I don't have my hands on `C` programming in windows as of now. :)

Comment: @Dchris below link might helps you.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the (theoretical) memory consumption:

```
printf("%d MB", (rows*columns*sizeof(int))/1024/1024);
```

.

You will have to use a new/malloc approach to get the most from it (definitely more than with your current approach on stack), i.e. if you use:

```
int *bigarray= new int[columns*rows];
```

and then access it as

```
val= bigarray[ x*columns + y];  // instead of bigarray[x][y];
```

With that, on modern platforms (Windows, Linux, etc.) and 32bit program you could expect to be reasonably ok with sizes of 500 - 1000 MB

Comment: how fast will it run for sizes of 500-1000MB?

Comment: What do you mean "how fast will it run"?  Run what?  Speed depends on what you do with it (read, compute, cross-search), and on the processor and memory and on how busy the computer is otherwise (how much memory allocated to other tasks).